# Duplicate symbol build error in Xcode project

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, debugging

When I try to build my project I get the following error.

> ld: duplicate symbol
>   .objc_class_name_GLFunView in
>   /Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/GLFun.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GLFun.build/Objects-normal/i386/GLFunView-7A51E8797CBB3D72.o
>   and
>   /Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/GLFun.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GLFun.build/Objects-normal/i386/GLFunView-7A51E8797CBB3D72.o

What is this error about? How can I track down where the error is? XCode usually highlights the code that has problems, but for this error it's not showing anything? It doesn't have anything to do with Interface Builder does it?

My research indicates that this might be caused by including something twice, but I don't understand how that's possible since I'm not using any #include statements, I'm only using #import statements.

Here's some more of the build output:

> Ld
>   build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GLFun.app/GLFun
>   normal i386 cd
>   /Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun
>   setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
>   setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/GLFun.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GLFun.build/Objects-normal/i386/GLFun.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES
>   -framework QuartzCore -o /Users/gin/Documents/development/GLFun/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GLFun.app/GLFun

Comment: You must be including something twice because the paths are the same.. does it say "Included from" in any of the build output?

Comment: Includes almost never cause linker errors. This one might be triggered by multiple includes if you have an `@implementation` in a header file… but if that's the case, then you have other problems.

Comment: I searched the whole project for @implementation and didn't find a single instance of it.

Comment: The build output doesn't say "included from" anywhere.

Comment: Peter, if the problem was an import that picked up an `@implementation` (and someone on #iphonedev had that very problem last week, they imported a .m by accident), the linker error would have listed two separate object files.

Comment: Actually, that does give me a thought. If both the .h and the .m use `@implementation` instead of using `@interface` in the .h, and no other .m imports GLFunView.h, then that would also cause this problem.

Answer (score 23):

I ran into the same problem today. It turned out to be a typo in an `#import` statement. I accidentally included the `.m` file instead of the header:

```
#include "MyClass.m"
```

instead of:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you're @implementing GLFunView twice in the same file (GLFunView.m). Perhaps you meant to implement GLFunView and then implement a category on it, and forgot the category name?

Comment: There is no @implementing in GLFunView.m.

Comment: no, but there's at least one `@implementation`. If you have 2 @implementation GLFunView lines, you're implementing the class twice. If you do have that, perhaps one was meant to be an `@implementation GLFunView (SomeCategory)`?

Comment: Or perhaps, as I mentioned in a comment above, your GLFunView.h has a `@implementation GLFunView` somewhere in it?

Comment: As I stated before I have used XCode's search function to look for "@implement" in the whole project and nothing was found.

Comment: @awakeFromNib, as theMikeSwan says, you absolutely need `@implementation` in order to create classes. If you really searched for "@implement", maybe you have find set on Whole Words? You really need to pop open GLFunView.m and actually look at what's in that file.